# Determining the size of power sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A very elementary question:

> Let $|A|=a$, and $|B|=b$. What's $|\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\mathcal P(A \times B \times \varnothing)))|$?

So how I got stuck on it: I'm not sure what's the number of pairs that a generic $A \times B$ gives, and what's $A \times B \times \varnothing$? Is it $A$ times $B$ times empty set? Sorry, I'm kinda confused on all of this subject and don't have a good source of knowledge (terrible lecturer and no textbook...).

P.S. Is there a good online source, or an eBook or whatever for discrete mathematics?

Thanks in advance for any help, tips etc.

Comment: $A\times B\times \varnothing=\{(a,b,c): \underbrace{a\in A \wedge b\in B\wedge \underbrace{c\in \varnothing}_{\text{Impossible}}}_{\text{Impossible}}\}=\varnothing$

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $$A\times B\times\varnothing=\varnothing.$$

Comment: Disregard. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

$$P(\emptyset)=\{\emptyset\}$$

$$P(P(\emptyset))=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$$

$$P(P(P(\emptyset)))=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$$

$$|P(P(P(A\times B\times \emptyset)))|=|P(P(P(\emptyset)))|=4$$